# cant seem to loop through object keys

Tags: javascript

I have an object through which im trying to loop through using for..in. But it gives me "0" as values instead of the object keys such as piidata, location, risklevel etc.

```
var srcObj = [{
    location: "34",
    piidata: "sdafa",
    risklevel: "Medium"
}]

for (var prop in srcObj) {
                console.log(prop);            
            }
```

[image: object]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`srcObj` is an array, as evidenced by the `[]`. Inside it is an object at index `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your "srcObj" is an array.  This is indicated by the wrapping `[ ... ]`.  If you `console.log` `srcObj[0]`, you should get the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do

```
for (var prop in srcObj) {
  console.log(srcObj[prop]);
  console.log(srcObj[prop]["risklevel"]); // --> Medium

  var keyNames = Object.keys(srcObj[prop]); // --> return keyNames as array
  console.log(keyNames[0], keyNames[1]); // --> location   piidata
}
```

Comment: Apologies, you're right. However, the OP asks for the property names of the object within `srcObj`, your code won't produce those.

Comment: Yes, downvote still there. Read my comment. The OP is asking for: *object keys such as `piidata`, `location`, `risklevel`*; which part of your snippet returns those?

Answer (score 0):

while you are looping the javascript object it's return the index/key of object

so if you are trying to get value of each key try.

```
for( var prop in srcObj ) 
{
    console.log(srcObj[prop]);            
}
```

if you are trying to get each key name then try this one

```
for( var prop in srcObj ) 
{
    console.log(prop);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your srcObj is an array.  You can tell by the square brackets [] it's enclosed in.  But Chrome says `Object`.  Right.  Javascript types are a little strange.  Check out [this page](https://toddmotto.com/understanding-javascript-types-and-reliable-type-checking/).

If you want to access the key/values in the object, you can specify the index of the object within the array.  `srcObj[0]` in this case.  If you want to get the object out of the array and deal with it just as an object, you can do something like this:

```
var trueObject = srcObj.shift()
```

Which removes and returns the first element of an array and assigns it to your variable.

Answer (score -1):

Your `srcObj` is actually an array (identified by the `[` and `]` literals) which contains an object as its only element.

To access the parameters of the single object inside the array, use the following syntax:

```
for( var prop in srcObj[0] ) 
{
    console.log(prop);            
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/s0azfaLx/1/)